# Is running code under a different user (impersonation) possible with a service account (domain) without a windows service?

Tags: c#, wpf, impersonation

We want to run a process under the context of a service account.
Can a method within a WPF application be executed (using Process.Start) impersonated with a service user account (domain) without a windows service?

If possible, how can this be achieved?

Comment: Was trying different ways, but still got the message:
"Login failed: The user does not have the required login type on this computer"

Comment: The complication with our approach is, that we have non-admin users and want to use a service user account to process operations on network shares. But I think the problem is, that the service user is not having rights to login to the machine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP:

> Can a method within a WPF application be executed (using Process.Start) impersonated with a service user account (domain) without a windows service?

You can impersonate a user regardless of what type the calling process is. i.e. *WPF, Windows Service, Console App*. It does not matter. However on **Windows Vista and later the process must be running as an *administrator***.

Example courtesy of [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext?view=netframework-4.8)

```
string userName, domainName;
// Get the user token for the specified user, domain, and password using the
// unmanaged LogonUser method.
// The local machine name can be used for the domain name to impersonate a user on this machine.
Console.Write("Enter the name of the domain on which to log on: ");
domainName = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("Enter the login of a user on {0} that you wish to impersonate: ", domainName);
userName = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("Enter the password for {0}: ", userName);

...

// Call LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token.
bool returnValue = LogonUser(userName, domainName, Console.ReadLine(),
                LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                out safeTokenHandle);
...

using (safeTokenHandle)
{
...

    using (WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle()))
    {
        using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate())
        {
            // Check the identity.
            Console.WriteLine("After impersonation: "
                             + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
        }
    }
}
```

For more information and the **complete example**, I recommend viewing the link above as I didn't wish to quote the entire sample.

### More

- *[WindowsImpersonationContext Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext?view=netframework-4.8)*
- *[Impersonating and Reverting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/impersonating-and-reverting)*

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!
How can this be done, by specifying a username, password for the service-user?

Comment: @SiL3NC3 you'rewelcome.  Whoops I forgot to include the important beginning bit - where the username/password is coming from.  **See edit**.  In your WPF app you can either have the user specify it in a login window or hard-code it

Comment: Great for adding this. :) Does impersonation always need administrator rights? Or is there a way without it? Not all domain users have them... Will have a look at the provided link. Thank you.

Comment: @SiL3NC3 only for pre-Vista sadly

Comment: Then I'm in trouble... ;) Thanks for providing the information, dude.

Comment: Just to be complete, I also got the same error with the MSDN code example as mentioned in the question's comment. Then we maybe need to change our approach...

Comment: As stated, impersonation requires the process to be running as an admin. There's **no way around it**.  Additionally regardng your last comments - _[Is it OK to make a clarifying edit to a question if it will invalidate existing answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266946/is-it-ok-to-make-a-clarifying-edit-to-a-question-if-it-will-invalidate-existing)_.  Please feel free to post a _new question_,